# Using smarty template engine with slim

Tags: php, html, smarty, slim

I am trying to setup Slim Framework with the use of Smarty, but something is very wrong.
I can output the template, but it renders the template with the markers and the the data which should replace the markers. In the .tpl I have a marker `{#currency#}`, but this is also what is printed when I call test.php/test/1

I have this in my test.php

```
require 'libs/Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
use Slim\Slim;

require 'libs/Slim/Extras/Views/Smarty.php';

$app = new Slim(array('view', new \Slim\Extras\Views\SmartyView()));

$app->get('/test/:id', function($id) use ($app) {   
    $adverts = new Adverts();
    $app->render('viewad.tpl', array(
        'viewad' => $adverts->viewsinglead($id),
        'imagelist' => $adverts->getadimages($id),
        'firstimage' => $adverts->getadimage($id)    
    ));
});

$app->run();
```

In libs/Slim/Extras/Views/Smarty.php I have set this:

```
public static $smartyDirectory = '/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.dk/web/libs/smarty/libs';
public static $smartyCompileDirectory = '/templates_c';
public static $smartyCacheDirectory = '/cache';
public static $smartyTemplatesDirectory = '/templates';
```

Comment: Quick note: You should not modify  libs/Slim/Extras/Views/Smarty.php directly. Instead you should obtain view object `$view = $app->view();` and set you parameters on this object as documented here: https://github.com/codeguy/Slim-Views#how-to-use Other issue is that you should not use absolute paths `$smartyDirectory` but relative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had an error in the array!
This fixed it:

```
$app = new Slim(array('view' => new \Slim\Extras\Views\SmartyView()));
```